# Is there the unique identifier of SD card in Android API? And how to get it?

Tags: android, local-storage, sd-card

Is there the unique identifier of SD card in Android API, And how to get it? How to distinguish between different SD card in my phone? I need the ID of SD card, please tell me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that there is no straight forward Java API in Android for that, as of now.

---

If you really need it, one way is to run the following commands and analyse the output (you can use terminal emulator app to test these):

```
mount
```

This will list mounted partitions, usually there will be a `/mnt/sdcard` and its related `/dev/sdb1` in its output. You can process output and find sd-card partitions you are interested in.

```
blkid
```

*This requires root access, that is, run `su` command first*. This will print block device info, and `/dev/sdb1` or so will have a UID associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to get SD Card id

```
public String getSDCardUniqueId()
    {
        String sd_cid = null;
        try {

            File file = new File("/sys/block/mmcblk1");
            String memBlk;
            if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {

                memBlk = "mmcblk1";
            } else {
                //System.out.println("not a directory");
                memBlk = "mmcblk0";
            }

            Process cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /sys/block/"+memBlk+"/device/cid");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmd.getInputStream()));
            sd_cid = br.readLine();
            //System.out.println(sd_cid);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sd_cid;
    }
```

Comment: Is this method general for Android? Or special circumstance to be available?  By the way, Where do you come from? Thanks

Comment: use this , and if working  dont forget to mark as answer so others also find this useful